# playwright._impl._api_types.Error: headers[6].value: expected string, got object

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-playwright

I am currently working with scrapy-playwright and trying to scrape the following url https://www.paniniamerica.net/checklist but got the following error

```
web_1         | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1         |   File "/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_connection.py", line 39, in send
web_1         |     return await self.inner_send(method, params, False)
web_1         |   File "/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_connection.py", line 63, in inner_send
web_1         |     result = next(iter(done)).result()
web_1         | playwright._impl._api_types.Error: headers[6].value: expected string, got object
```

**System info**

- Playwright Version: 1.19
- Operating System: Ubuntu 18
- Browser: Chromium
- Other info:

  - Scrapy Version: ^2.7.1
  - Scrapy-Playwright: ^0.0.26

Couldn't get by this happening. Please see the spider code bellow

```
class ExSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "ex_spider"
    custom_settings = {
        'TWISTED_REACTOR': 'twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor',
        'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy.dupefilters.BaseDupeFilter',
        'DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS': {
            "https": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
            "http": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
        },
        'SCRAPY_PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSER_TYPE': 'chromium',
        'PLAYWRIGHT_DEFAULT_NAVIGATION_TIMEOUT': 0 * 1000,
        'PLAYWRIGHT_CONTEXTS': {
            "default": {
                "viewport": {
                    "width": 1920,
                    "height": 980,
                }
            }
        },
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 20,
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 20,
        'CONCURRENT_ITEMS': 20,
        'REACTOR_THREADPOOL_MAXSIZE': 20,
        'RETRY_TIMES': 3,
        'PLAYWRIGHT_ABORT_REQUEST': should_abort_request,
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        url = "https://www.paniniamerica.net/checklist"
        logger.info("Start the scraper")
        req = scrapy.Request(url,
                             callback=self.parse_type,
                             meta=dict(
                                 playwright=True,
                                 playwright_context="default",
                                 errback=self.errback,
                                 playwright_include_page=True,
                                 playwright_page_methods=[
                                     PageMethod("wait_for_selector", "select#damage_type", timeout=0 * 1000,
                                                state="visible"),
                                     PageMethod("wait_for_load_state", "load")
                                 ]
                             ))
        print(req.headers)
        yield req

    async def parse_type(self, response):
        print("Here")
        page = response.meta["playwright_page"]
        await page.close()
        logger.info("Check point")
        select_types = response.css("select#damage_type::text").extract()
        logger.info(f"select type are {select_types}")
```

Thanks in advance